# Get many-to-one relationships to display both ways in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models in my Django app file `models.py` like so:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,max_length=5)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
class Device(models.Model):
    device_name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=30)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
```

Each `Device` can only have one `User`, but each `User` can have more than one `Device`.

In the admin interface, when I display a `Device` it shows the `User` in a drop-down list, but when I display the `User`, I don't see the associated `Device`.  How do I fix this so I can see the relationship from either side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [InlineModelAdmin objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

**UPD**

Should look like:

```
class DeviceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Device

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        DeviceInline
    ]
```

Comment: I'll add my solution to your answer :o) - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StackedInline with extra=0 option.

```
class DeviceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = User
    extra = 0

    def has_add_permission(request):
        return True or False # change for your context
```